# Flask App Apscheduler not working in background deployed on heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

In my flask app I want to schedule a function to run in a regular time interval which I have deployed on **heroku**. Which works perfectly when the interval is in few minutes or seconds but not for hours. I am using Aps Scheduler.

Here is my python file which contains the scheduler.

```
#price_drop.py

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
schedule = BackgroundScheduler()

def CheckPrice():
    print("Running")

schedule.add_job(id= "Tracker",func = CheckPrice,trigger='interval',hours = 1)
schedule.start()
```

There are other features which should run in parallel(routes).

run.py

```
from app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

Here are some heroku configurations

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn app:app
clock: python price_drop.py
```

Also Added below command in powershell

**heroku ps:scale clock=1**

> I think the scheduler is running in background so I need to keeping the file alive. Can plz anyone suggest me an efficient way to do this. Or am I going wrong anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run actual computation within the clock process. It is not the way to handle scheduled executions in heroku.

You'll need

- A single clock process (like the one you already have).  Which will queue tasks in a message queue like redis
- A worker process that listens to redis queue and processes tasks
- A message queue like redis

Here some guides about achieving what you want

- [Scheduled Jobs with Custom Clock Processes in Python with APScheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python)
- [Background Tasks in Python with RQ](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq)

If you are not planning on scaling up the web worker beyond 1, you can directly add APScheduler within the Flask app.